# Magento 2.2 REST API get categorie in product list

Tags: magento2, rest-api

When I do `GET /rest/V1/products/prodID`, in response (custom_attributes field) I have

```
{
     "attribute_code": "category_ids",
     "value": [
        "2",
        "3",
        "20"
      ]
 }
```

but if i do `GET /rest/V1/products?searchCriteria`, 
and get product list,  **"custom_attributes"** don't have **"attribute_code"**: **"category_ids"**
what can i do for have **"category_ids"** in magento rest api response?

Comment: Is this a custom attribute? If so, you would probably have to go via the `extension_attributes` path to add it to the correct controller. See here as an example: https://www.atwix.com/development/adding-custom-attribute-to-api-response-in-magento-2/

Comment: If you mean the existing attribute you may just need to add it to the correct group in the catalog_attributes.xml via a custom module. `<group name="catalog_product"><attribute name="category_ids" /></group>`

Answer (score 0):

The `getList` on `Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository` which provides you `GET /rest/V1/products?searchCriteria` already supported your response with `category_ids`

See

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/ProductRepository.php#L685

You don't have to do anything from this, you'd just make sure products were belong to some categories.